# Stopping a flink job automatically when all required events from an unbounded source are processed

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, streaming, flink-sql

We have a flink (using BEAM ) job with DAG

```
source -> filter -> sink
```

The source is Kafka, it's unbounded and we want events only from a specific time period. There is a field `timestamp` in the event in the filter clause

something like

```
select * from PCOLLECTION where timestamp > 2023-09-10T00:00:00 and timestamp < 2023-09-11T00:00:00
```

We want to stop the job automatically when all the required events are sent to the sink. Can someone please suggest a way to do this in Flink ? We were planning to do it outside of flink using the consumergroup offsets to track if all the events are processed. Is there any better way to accomplish the same ?

Answer (score 2):

In Flink, you can use `KafkaSourceBuilder` to set the start and end timestamps:

```java
KafkaSource
    .<String>builder()
    .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.timestamp(<start-timestamp>))
    .setBounded(OffsetsInitializer.timestamp(<end-timestamp>))
    ...
```

Using the table API:

```
'scan.startup.mode' = 'timestamp',
'scan.startup.timestamp-millis' = '<start-timestamp>',
'scan.bounded.mode' = 'timestamp',
'scan.bounded.timestamp-millis' = '<end-timestamp>'
```

Comment: we are using BEAM over flink and it uses KafkaIO instead of KafkaSourceBuilder. Do you know if there is an alternative in KafkaIO for setBounded ?